# [Real analysis](Lower sums behave like a monotonic sequence converging to its lower integral)

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Apologies if stupid question, not super experienced in analysis, only my second class.

A lower bounded monotonically decreasing sequence always converges to its infimum, and moreover, for any given refinement $P^*$ of an interval for $P$ of $L(P,f, \alpha$), some interval gets broken apart such that $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ becomes two intervals, say $[x_{i-1}, x_{i.5}]$ and $[x_{i,5}, x_{i}]$. By definition, the inf on the first set is relegated to either one of the broken apart sets, or exactly on the middle point (in both sets).

In either case, you have that the new inf's for the two broken apart sets are greater than or equal to that inf, so you get a $L(P^*, f, \alpha)$ >= $L(P, f, \alpha)$ for each refinement.

Moreover, if you just make that new refinement be just "one" additional point, then what you have is a monotonically increasing sequence. In fact, every partition can be refined into a monotonically increasing sequence that has $L(P,f,\alpha)$ tending towards its supremum.

Moreover, we know that if the integral exists, this sequence has to converge to that value.

Does that mean we can characterize the integral as a sequence with "left-hand side" values and "right-hand side" values, just like the limit of a function?*

If so does that mean literally all of the objects we learn in real analysis can just be thought of as sequences? For example, continuity can be entirely defined in terms of sequences and so can limits. Derivatives are just limits at a point/set, so those are sequences as well.

*Moreover, does this somehow relate to the infinite series definition an integral? Intuitively, I feel those things do not connect but I cannot tell the difference either way.

Thanks!

edit:

Thought of an equivalent  condition: all infinite non-repeating sequences of the Partition on $[a,b]$ is such that they force $L(P,f,\alpha)$ to tend towards its sup. Dunno if that's good for anything. Can someone shed some insight as to what is going on structurally?

Comment: What is the infinite series definition of an integral?  All the definitions I've seen are limits/nets of finite sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand, but I think I get enough of a general thrust to be able to answer satisfactorily.

As you have observed, sequences and their limits pop up everywhere in real analysis, to the point that, when it came time to define the Riemann integral, their absence was suspicious. Why was the Riemann integral defined as a supremum of a set (or the infimum of another set, assumed to be equal), instead of a nice easy sequence that we could compute and approximate?

The answer is, essentially, this is the most intuitive definition, and is most easy to deal with. One can indeed define the Riemann integral of a Riemann integrable function, just by defining it as a limit of uniform left-Riemann sums. That is, if we have a Riemann-integrable function $f$ over $[a, b]$, then we could define:
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x := \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(a + i\Delta x) \Delta x, \quad \text{where } \Delta x = \frac{b - a}{n}.$$
This is, indeed, a sensible definition of the Riemann integral (taking for granted that Riemann integrability is already defined).

But, instantly, a natural question arises: why did we choose to sample from the left endpoint? What if we chose to sample from the right endpoint? Or the midpoint? Or maybe, the point that lies half as far from the left endpoint as it does from the right? Could we vary the point from which we sample, from interval to interval? What is so special about the left endpoint?

Now, one can show that, for a Riemann integrable function, all of these variations produce the same number. But this requires proof, and it suggests that there's something more simple, more elegant, and more fundamental under the surface.

Think about, for example, the identity:
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 f(1 - x) \, \mathrm{d}x,$$
which can be intuited by considering the graph of $f$ reflected about the line $x = 1/2$. If we were to argue with left Riemann sums alone, it would be slightly clunky to argue this equality. You would naturally want to reflect the left Riemann sum picture about $x = 1/2$, but this would turn a left Riemann sum into a right Riemann sum! You would have to show that the left and right Riemann sums converge to the same number, and admit that the choice of left Riemann sum was somewhat arbitrary.

There's also the issue that left and right uniform Riemann sums are not sufficient to define Riemann integrability. The indicator function on the rationals will have left and right Riemann sums of $1$, over any interval $[a, b]$ where $a, b \in \Bbb{Q}$. But, the function is not Riemann integrable.

Then, there's the more advanced issue of partitions. Why does it always have to be uniform partitions? Is there anything special about them? It could make sense to consider other partitions in certain circumstances (e.g. if your function changes more rapidly in one part of the interval than the other, and you want to save computation time, you could get better estimates by adding more parts where the function rapidly changes). Do we need yet another proof that the choice of uniform partition was just arbitrary?

The definition involving uniform left-Riemann sums can be generalised to remove arbitrary assumptions of left-sampling, and uniform partitions. This takes much proof, but it's all possible. However, it's considered best practice to base your definition around the more general case, and let the specific cases fall from there, rather than begin with a specific case with arbitrary choices, and prove generality. That's one reason why we define the Riemann integral as a supremum of lower Riemann sums. Another reason is that we get a neat characterisation of Riemann integrability (that doesn't assume continuity): the supremum of lower sums must be the same as the infimum of upper sums.

From this definition, we can show a powerful result characterisation involving sequences:

> Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and $\mathcal{P}_n$ is a sequence of partitions of $[a, b]$ such that $\operatorname{mesh} \mathcal{P}_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (the mesh of a partition is the length of its longest interval). Suppose that $r_n$ is a Riemann sum of $f$ over the partition $\mathcal{P}_n$ (choosing any sample points from $\mathcal{P}_n$). Then $r_n \to \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ as $n \to \infty$.

That is, it doesn't matter what sequence of partitions you use, so long as the longest part approaches $0$, and it doesn't matter where you sample from the interval. This includes uniform left/right/mid Riemann sums! If the function is Riemann integrable, all of these sequences will approach the same value. In this way, we have gone from a general, intuitive, neat characterisation, to a bunch of sequences that can help us accurately approximate the true value of the integral.

Note, this is not quite what you stated in your edit. "Non-repeating" is not sufficient to guarantee convergence. For example, if you take the non-repeating partitions $\{[0, 1/n], [1/n, 1]\}$ over $[0, 1]$, then the lower Riemann sum of any continuous function will just tend to the minimum of $f$, not the integral, over $[0, 1]$. Even if you insist on each interval becoming finer than the last, it's still not enough, e.g.
$$\left\{\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right],\left[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}\right], \ldots, \left[\frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2^{n-1}}, \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}\right], \left[\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}, 1\right] \right\}$$
is a sequence of partitions that becomes finer at each step, but due to the intervals like $[0, 1/2]$ not breaking down further, the Riemann sums over these partitions will not approximate the integral. (Note: the lower Riemman sums will still increase, but they just won't increase all the way to the integral!)

So, though sequences of Riemann sums are sufficient to calculate the integral, they are not the best tool for defining the integral.

---

To finish up this already over-long answer, this somewhat unfamiliar object of *all* partitions, sampling schemes over these partitions, and the Riemann sums over them, does indeed belong to a larger type of mathematical object in analysis: it is an example of a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)).

Nets are a generalisation of sequences (with the power to be much "larger" than sequences), used in the study of topological spaces. The real line is a kind of toplogical space, and it is a specific type called a [Sequential Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space). What it (very roughly) means is that sequences can be used pretty much to do everything (as you noted in your question). In more general spaces, sometimes sequences don't give you the "whole story", in which case, nets are necessary.

While a sequence is a function defined on the natural numbers, a net is defined on a particular type of partially ordered set (or poset) called a *directed set*. In our case, the directed set is the set of partitions with given sample points (i.e. the same partition, but with different sample points, would be considered a different point in our directed set). The partial order is a little complicated, but we say that one partition $\mathcal{P}$ (with sample points) is "greater" than another $\mathcal{Q}$ if

- $\mathcal{P}$ is finer than $\mathcal{Q}$, and
- the sample points of $\mathcal{Q}$ still appear in $\mathcal{P}$, in the sense that however $[x_{i-1}, x_i] \in \mathcal{Q}$ is subdivided in $\mathcal{P}$, the sample point for $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ appears in one of the subdivided intervals of $\mathcal{P}$.

The net on this directed set is the Riemann sum of the given real function $f$, over the interval, with given sample points. This function is much larger than a sequence, but it is a sensible net. So, rather than defining the Riemann integral as a limit of a sequence, it is the limit of a net instead!

Now, as I said before, $\Bbb{R}$ is a sequential space, so sequences are sufficient for most things. As I established before, sequences are indeed sufficient to calculate Riemann integral, which can be concluded from the fact that $\Bbb{R}$ is a sequential space. But, being a sequence space doesn't guarantee that sequences are the best tool for defining the Riemann integral, which they are not!